# Error de compilacion en dispositivo movil con xamarin.forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xdebug

Intento compilar una app en un dispositivo movil `android 7.0 Xiomi Redmi note 4` pero es como si lo estuviera haciendo en un emulador.

El **error** que me muestra es el siguiente:

> Error de compilación: Xamarin.Android no admite la ejecución de la versión anterior. Asegúrese de que se compila la solución antes de ejecutarla o depurarla.

Espero puedan colaborarme , saludos.

[image: error que sale en el compilador]

Answer (score 1):

Busca en tu proyecto el API target, es muy probable que este seleccionada una versión de android menor a la que se debe utilizar.

En proyecto -> propiedades cambia la version target(objetivo) y de compilación a la deseada.