# Xamarin.Android no admite la ejecución de la versión anterior. Asegúrese de que se compila la solución antes de ejecutarla o depurarla

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Amigos cree un nuevo proyecto, completamente vacío y me aparece este error

> Error de compilación: Xamarin.Android no admite la ejecución de la versión anterior. Asegúrese de que se compila la solución antes de ejecutarla o depurarla.
>   Iniciar la depuración de la aplicación Android ...
>   Iniciando la aplicación Android ...
>   Error. Vea la excepción completa en los registros para más información.
>   No se puede iniciar la depuración.El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado.

Alguien sabe a que se deba? no he hecho nada, solo cree el proyecto, nada más.

Comment: Estas usando una maquina virtual?, y mira esta pregunta ya se había hecho aquí mira si esa solución te funciona: [Error de compilacion en dispositivo movil con xamarin.forms](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/158469/69447)

Comment: Hola, no nada de maquina virtual, si ya revisé ese link antes, pero me no ayudo mucho :s